# NodeJs express-session don´t save the session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I´ve a problem by saving something in the session above a NodeJs Script. If I start the script and making a post login like this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   sess = req.session;
   sess.key = "SecureKEy";
   console.log(sess);
});
```

I got as rusult that what I want:

> Session {
>     cookie: 
>      { path: '/',
>        _expires: null,
>        originalMaxAge: null,
>        httpOnly: true },
>     key: 'SecureKEy' }

But if I reload the page with this code the session.key is empty. Just like it´s not saved.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   sess = req.session;
   console.log(sess);
   res.sendFile(__dirname+'/wwwroot/index.html');
});
```

My configuration for the express-session is this:

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
   secret: 'importent',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: Always declare variables!

Comment: the sess will be globaly declated

Comment: And thats a design mistake. You cant access the session outside of the request handler.

Comment: Sorry, but where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I´ve rewrite the code like this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   console.log("Before: ");
   console.log(sess);
   sess = req.session;
   sess.key = "SecureKEy";
   req.session.save();
   console.log("After: ");
   console.log(sess);
});
```

With that it work correctly. But if I would resend the logged in page with res.send the session would be automaticly saved? Is that correct?

Comment: this isn't a good test because you're testing within the same request, within the same code block. To truly test you would make another request from the same session and see if it can retrieve the saved data from the previous request. After you login, you would make another request to /check and in there it would just have a `req.session.key` value present

Answer (score 1):

**express-session *auto-save* edge cases?**

The express-session `save(...)` method is certainly not triggered for some express response transport methods. It seems to trigger consistently for the frequently encountered ones such as `response.send(...)`, `response.json(...)` etc.

But same is not the case for the special case transport method such as the `express.response.end()` method - from my observation at least; and also `response.sendFile(...)` according to the OP and `response.redirect(...)` according to posts elsewhere.

To avoid unforeseen issue, pay close attention when applying express-session to requests where special case response transport methods were used. **The express-session `save(...)` method may have to be called directly to persist changes made during those requests.** Even then, there is no guarantee that persistence would take place.

For example, there are occasions where setting values to null and/or calling the `session.destroy(...)` and/or `session.regenerate(...)` methods have no effect. Those *destructed* session data basically resurface on the next page refresh. Not even calling the `save(...)` method or setting the `unset` option to `'destroy'` can remedy that situation.

The express-session *readme* should include these edge case scenarios in one of its **Note** sections at the top of the page. It would curb some of the headwinds surrounding its ***auto-save*** feature.

My philosophy to this type of thing is: when a package is too quirky for a use-case, either find a more suited package or just source your own solution if possible. Workarounds tend to warp application logic thereby making it error prone and difficult to maintain over time.